# I am looking for an IDE like a Pyscripter for coding Python

Tags: software-recommendation, python, ide

I was using Pyscripter on Windows, but there is not a version for Ubuntu.

I want three functions in the IDE:

1. Editor(it has function 2-auto-completion)
2. Auto-completion (dynamic indicate by the words about "import",imported object,variables defined in editor, and so on.)
3. Python-interpreter (possible to deal with the variables in the editor after runs editor)

Do you know of any IDE that has these features?

Now, [Wing IDE Personal](http://wingware.com/downloads/wingide-personal) has become a candidate, and it is closest to what I have asked for but it is too expensive for me. If possible, I want free software.

Comment: In *my opinion*, PyCharm is the best you can get. But such questions are better asked on [softwarerecs.se] I think. They're too broad and opinion-based for this site.

Comment: I use Spyder and PyCharm. But it can be very opinion bases.

Answer (score 2):

Me I recommend you PyCharm of the JetBrains company. This is not a free software but the quality is higher than others. Very useful and professional tool for developing.

Comment: You should add explanations on how to install it for example.

Comment: version professional is too expensive for me. But PyCharm-community is free and it was suit to me. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to set enable auto-completion when I'm typing on the console ?

Comment: I'm use PHPStorm (same JetBrains company and principle of software) and I have auto-completion on my console login by SSH on my vagrant whithout extra parameters. You can easy fix that by post issue on StckOverflo with pycharm tag I think. Good luck and this company software release very good and quality software.

Answer (score 2):

I use [**PyDev**](http://www.pydev.org/), the Python plug-in for Eclipse.

[image]

Main features:

- Django integration
- Code completion
- Code completion with auto import
- Type hinting
- Code analysis
- Go to definition
- Refactoring
- Debugger
- Remote debugger
- Find Referrers in Debugger
- Tokens browser
- Interactive console
- Unittest integration
- Code coverage
- Find References

And of course, it is fully open source.

If you do not intend to use Eclipse for any other language, then you might prefer [**LiClipse**](http://www.liclipse.com/images/theming.png), a pre-bundled Eclipse/PyDev release.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Eric Python IDE](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) is great and has lots of features like auto completion, error highlighting, debugging and is nicely laid out for managing large projects.  You can also design forms.  It has everything I need to get started with Python projects.

Best of all, it's easy to install with just `sudo apt-get install eric` or visit the Software Center and install from there.

[image: Eric]

Comment: Only thing I really miss on eric6 is a snippets plugin.

Comment: @Videonauth - the Templates function of eric6 is probably what you need - Window > Windows > Template viewer (Alt-Shift-A). Help is available after you add a group and add an entry.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Stani's Python IDE. You can install it from Ubuntu Software Center. Just type 'python spe' on the search box.

Comment: I tried using the SPE in response to your opinion. It is nice. but auto-complete function was not sufficient that my wished. Thank you for  answering.

Answer (score 0):

I use sublime text with modules like anaconda, fold python, bracket highliter, auto brackets, google translate, file system autocompletion and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For beginners I recommend Thonny (http://thonny.org)

- It comes with Python 3.5 built in (ie you need single installer to get started)
- The initial interface is minimal (in order not to overwhelm beginners)
- It has comprehensive visualization support (step through statements and expressions). See more details at the homepage.

[image: Thonny stepping through recursive function]

Answer (score 0):

I think Geany is great. It's lightweight, starts up instantly, and is simple and easy to use.

Install: `sudo apt install geany`

[image: screenshot]